# Why custom attributes of product does not show on Admin Order Creation?

Tags: custom-attributes, admin-order-create

Adding products to order (Create new orders) via admin, When configuring them shows only the custom options. I would like to see the "Custom Attributes" like 'Manufacturers', 'Colors', 'Size' etc. Same as the Frontend / Customer interface. So that administrator can select the custom attributes for each products when creating order via admin. Hope this should be addressed somewhere?.. but I couldn't get this solved / find out from google.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason they aren't shown is that they aren't set on a per-order basis. Attributes like manufacturer shouldn't change for different orders of the same product, they are the same for all instances of that product. If the user can select who actually makes the product, then it would make sense to make it an option, but I don't think that's what you are asking.

I think you could solve your issue by looking at how your catalog and products are structured. If you have attributes that should be editable by the end user, you could look at making them custom options or possibly doing a configurable product.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4870537/2813046) is a good answer on the difference between product options and attributes.

Comment: If that was a case we have an option to edit / set custom price for "Price" attribute, isn't ?